# Does this limit exist? $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{φ(f(n))}{ψ(g(n))}$

Tags: calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

**EDİTED:**

Is this statement true?

> Suppose $\left\{f,g,\varphi, \psi \right\}:\mathbb{R^{+}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{+}}$ and for $n\to\infty$ 
>   $\left\{f(n),g(n),\varphi(n), \psi(n) \right\}\rightarrow \infty$
>
> If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{φ(n)}{ψ(n)}$ doesn't exist, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{φ(f(n))}{ψ(g(n))}$ doesn't exist too.

I want to know that, if the assumption is wrong, under what conditions is true?

Comment: That depends heavily on $f$ and $g$ ...

Comment: As an example: For constant $f=c_1$ and $g=c_2$ the limit will always exist.

Comment: I suppose that the limit is taking along the natural numbers, is that true?

Comment: The second statement looks like a statement about subsequences. I hope you know that a non convergent sequence might have a convergent subsequence... So from this you can already see that the statement can not be true.

Comment: @Shashi yes for positive integers., No, I did not know. The last thing you said, I learned now.

Comment: @Beginner I have added an answer. I hope it gives you insights on sequences.

Answer (score 0):

The statement depends on the choice of $f$ and $g$ as mentioned in the comments. So as it stands now, the claim is not true.

Just consider sequences that satisfy 
$$\frac{\phi(n) } {\psi(n) } = 2+ (-1)^n$$
The limit of that sequence is clearly non-existent. How can we get that? Well just set $\psi(n) =n$ and
$$\phi(n) =\psi(n) (2+ (-1)^n) $$
Now set $f(n) =g(n) =2n$ and see that they all satisfy the conditions mentioned by you. Let's see
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\phi(f(n) ) } {\psi(g(n) ) }=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2+1=3$$
That proves your claim wrong.

Honestly, I can't think of assumptions that make your statement true.